# Get document id after uploading it to SharePoint using the same web service

Tags: 2010, development, web-services

Does any one knows how to get the document id after uploading it to sharepoint using a single web service? So by using one call i can upload the document and get it's id.

I looked at ***Copy.asmx***  web service, but it returns zero to indicate that the operation has been completed and a result that does not contain the document id.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the List Item ID or Document id based on Document url using SiteData webservice.

We can use **SiteData.GetURLSegments** method, by passing document url and then we can retrive the List ID, WebId and Document id.

For ref, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774739(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Ok. But i will need two web services calls. one to upload the document using Copy.asmx, and the other to get it's id using SiteData.asmx. Can i upload the document and get it's id with one service call?

Comment: no as far as I know, you can not achieve this with one service call

Comment: No, we can't achieve the requirement with single web service call. Copy service especially for uploading document, so we can't get the   document id from this web service. So we have to go for another webservice.

Answer (score -2):

do you try to make a EventHandler? you can save the document id on a new column created by yourself, I don't understand so much the question but I think can be useful for you...
greetings!

MCS