# How to get the Document ID?

Tags: document-id

Is there a way to get the Document ID for the item just got uploaded?

```
using (Copy copyService = new Copy())
{
    copyService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    copyService.Url = "http://webserver/site/_vti_bin/copy.asmx";

    copyService.Timeout = 600000;

    uint itemId = copyService.CopyIntoItems(destinationUrl , destinationUrlArray, fields, xmlByteArray, out resultsArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to load the item in a subsequent call since the Document ID is generated separately.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18117/get-document-id-after-uploading-it-to-sharepoint-using-the-same-web-service